# react + redux + normalizer: How to send conditional denormalized data?

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

For example, simple *country-region* selection task (two comboboxes)
I select '*country*' from first combobox and keep it ID in component state. Next, I have to load '*regions*' for selected *country* ID - doing this in some dispatch method. Its all work perfect. Ok, redux store contains all nessesary data...All I need is send loaded *regions* to component...
BUT!
in *mapStateToProps* I do not have components state (selected '*country*' ID), so I need to pass all '*regions*' (for all countries) to component props... okey...

I'm using *normalizr* and all data in Redux store are normalized. And denormalization require all entities (because of references), so I must pass all redux store to component props... it seems not okey: denormalization is not components duty, *mapStateToProps* is most apropriate place for that, but denormalization all *regions* (no country ID in *mapStateToProps*) can consume too much time...

Whats the best practies for such task?

Comment: What did you dispatch to load regions? Didn’t you dispatch country id?

Answer (score 0):

The [normalized-reducer](https://github.com/brietsparks/normalized-reducer) library provides a way to manage normalized state without writing any reducer logic and includes a [normalizr adapter](https://github.com/brietsparks/normalized-reducer#normalizr-integration) that can transform your normalizr output into reducer-compatible initial state.

Comment: how it can helps? Main problem: there is no relations in schemas between country & regions... and I want some *control state* in one of *connect* args: mapStateToProps/mergeProps... another way: make specific dispatch-props func, that will return good data, but with twice rerender... I'm newbie with react/redux, so I like to know best practice for such tasks (filtering complex normalized data in react-redux)

Comment: can you please provide a small example your normalized data

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure if appretiate solution, but with HOC (custom withDynamicProps method) it seems to work:

```
import React from "react";

function withDynamicProps(Component, initalProps = {}) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = initalProps;
      this.setDynamicProps = this.setDynamicProps.bind(this);
    }

    setDynamicProps(dynamicProp) {
      this.setState(dynamicProp);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Component
          {...this.props}
          {...this.state}
          setDynamicProps={this.setDynamicProps}
        />
      );
    }
  };
}

export { withDynamicProps };
```

and in my *container*-component:

```
class ContainerComponent extends Component {
  ....

  componentDidMount() {
    const { countryId } = this.props;

    loadCountries();

    if (countryId) {
      loadRegions(countryId);
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { prevState} = this.props;

    if (countryId && prevState.countryId !== countryId) {
      loadRegions(countryId);
    }
  }

  onCountryChangeHandler(countryId) {
    this.props.setDynamicProps({ countryId });
  }

  render() {
    const { countriesList, regionsList, countryId } = this.props;

    return (
      <PresentationComponent {...this.props}/>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const {
    countryId
  } = ownProps;

  const {
    entities: { countries, regions },
    associativitiesRefs: { regionsByCountry }
  } = state;

  const countriesList = Object.keys(countries).map(x =>
    denormalize(countries[x], Schemas.COUNTRY, state.entities)
  );

  const regionsIdByCountry = regionsByCountry[countryId] || {
    ids: []
  };

  const regionsList = regionsIdByCountry.ids.map(x =>
    denormalize(regions[x], Schemas.REGION, state.entities)
  );

  return {
    countriesList,
    regionsList
  };
};

export default withDynamicProps(
  withRouter(
    connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      {
        loadCountries,
        loadRegions
      }
    )(ContainerComponent)
  )
);
```